# Springboot Pessimistic Locking

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-data-jpa, pessimistic-locking

I have trying to achieve row level locking in the postgres DB.Below is the sample code

Repository :

```
@Repository
public interface DeploymentRepository extends JpaRepository<Deployment,Long> {
   @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
   List<Deployment> findByStatus(Status status);
 }
```

Scheduler function calling lockable method:

```
@Scheduled(initialDelay = 1000, fixedRate = 10000)
public void checkStatus(){

    try {
        for (Deployment deployment : deploymentRepository.findByStatus(someStatus)) {

           //some method call

        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        logger.error("",e);

    }
}
```

I am running this on kubernetes with 3 replicas(3 instance of the scheduler is running).

My use case is the 
1. Data fetched by deploymentRepository.findByStatus(someStatus) in one instance should not fetch in other instance of scheduler until controller exists from for loop.

Error :

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:402) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153) ~[spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$ExposeRepositoryInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:364) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy117.findByStatus(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.microfocus.resourcepoolmanagement.schedule.DeplyomentStatusUpdate.checkStatus(DeplyomentStatusUpdate.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) [spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_231]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_231]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_231]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_231]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_231]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_231]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_231]
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1532) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:403) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.getResultList(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:129) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) ~[spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
... 25 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue.

However, using `@Transactional` in the Service class method alone did not solve this problem. I used the `@Transactional` annotation in the Repository `findBy` method as well.

This ensured that both of them were running in the same transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I missed to put transaction annotation

```
 @Scheduled(initialDelay = 1000, fixedRate = 10000)
 @Transactional
 public void checkStatus(){

  try {
    for (Deployment deployment : deploymentRepository.findByStatus(someStatus)) {

       //some method call

    }
}catch (Exception e){
    logger.error("",e);

}
  }
```